# Is there a way to combine git commands atomically (not through shell)?

Tags: git

Say, I want to do this:

```
git checkout featureBranch
git rebase master
```

If I want to combine the two "shell" commands I can do:

```
git checkout featureBranch && git rebase master
```

However, that is not atomic. If the `git checkout` command fails for some reason, the working directory will not be in the same state as before, nor in the final expected state. Also, other processes, such as my IDE, might be able to see the intermediate state between the two commands.

**Does `git` provide a way to combine two actions atomically?**

I don't need complete file-system level atomicity. That is, if the combined action requires 10 files in the working directory to be changed, it is okay if other processes can observe these 10 changes individually.

Edit: The above two commands are just for illustration. Also, it could be 3 or more commands that need to be chained.

Answer (score 4):

According to the `man git-rebase` these commands can be merged:

```
If <branch> is specified, git rebase will perform an automatic git checkout
<branch> before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.
```

So you could just run:

```
git rebase master remoteBranch
```

However there is no general solution.